# Getopt '?' case is never matched?

Tags: c, getopt

I have the following getopt code. Everything matches as intended expect for the '?'. I've added the getopt code with the usage statement below. I also have a print statement inside the '?' that doesn't print, making sure that it is not matching. I don't know why it won't match with the '?'.

This is what I tried in the terminal.

> ./bmptool -?

```
  static char usage[] = "Usage: bmptool [-s scale | -r degree | -f ] [-o output_file] [input_file] \n";

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "s:r:fo:")) != -1)
        switch (c) {
        //scale image
        case 's':
            //check if user already entered this case
            if(sFlag > 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error! s case used multiple times!\n");
                fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);  //print usage statement
                exit(-1);
            }
            sFlag = 1; //scale image
            checkNum(optarg);    // check if user entered integer
            scale = atoi(optarg); //optarg string convert to int

            //make sure user entered positive int
            if (scale < 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"'%d' is not a postive integer. To scale an image a positive "
                        "number must be entered.\n", scale );
                fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);  //print usage statement
                exit(-1);
            }
            countCase+=2;
            break;

        //rotate image
        case 'r':
            //check if user already entered this case
            if(rFlag > 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error! r case used multiple times!\n");
                fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);  //print usage statement
                exit(-1);
            }

            rFlag = 1;            //rotate image
            checkNum(optarg);    // check if user entered integer
            rotation = atoi(optarg); //optarg string convert to int

            //make sure user entered int that is a multiple of 90
            if (rotation % 90 != 0 )
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"'%d' is not multiple of 90. To rotate an image a number that is a multiple "
                        "of 90 must be entered.\n", rotation );
                fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);  //print usage statement
                exit(-1);
            }
            countCase+=2;
            break;

        //flip image
        case 'f':
            //check if user already entered this case
            if(fFlag > 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error! f case used multiple times!\n");
                fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);  //print usage statement
                exit(-1);
            }
            fFlag = 1; //flip image
            countCase++;
            break;

        //output to output file given by user
        case 'o':
            //check if user already entered this case
            if(oFlag > 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error! o case used multiple times!\n");
                fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);  //print usage statement
                exit(-1);
            }
            oFlag = 1;
            outPutFileName = (char*) malloc(strlen(optarg));
            strcpy(outPutFileName, optarg);
            countCase += 2;
            break;
        case '?':
            printf("in here\n");
            err = 1;
            break;
        }

    if (err || optind + 1 < argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Why not printf out the 'c' var, and its ASCII value, just before the switch, to see what it actually returned?  That would be a normal act of debugging....

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I just tried that and it gave me 'f'. Don't know how that happened.